# How to politely decline the request by the employer even if they offer me the desired salary after resigning

Tags: salary, manager, appraisal

I have resigned my current organisation and got an offer with another company with 25% hike

But the managers are pressurizing me to stay here currently. But I don't want to stay here as I don't like the work environment

After my manager asked me many times that what would make me stay in the current company, I told that I have an offer with 25% hike and succumbed to pressure and hiding the actual reason, I said, if you can provide the same or near to the current hike as the other company, I would revert my resignation. But that's not the actual reason. I just don't like working here. I just thought that If I hide the actual reason and say that I have received a 25% hike, they would not be able to match that hike and make me stay here. But will they go to that extent to give a 25% hike?

My questions :

1. Will the current company provide me a 25% and make me stay here itself or they won't?
2. Suppose, they provide the desired hike, But I don't want to stay there, how to politely decline and move out?

Comment: You should wait 24 hours before accepting any answer, otherwise you end up chopping and changing each time an answer appears as you have proved...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I quit gracefully, without burning any bridges?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100473/how-do-i-quit-gracefully-without-burning-any-bridges)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you decline to give a reason, and ask to not attempt to be retained when you resign?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93640/can-you-decline-to-give-a-reason-and-ask-to-not-attempt-to-be-retained-when-you)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say act quickly.

If your manager goes to bat for you, explaining to the CFO how important you are and why she should release extra budget, and then you still leave, that will cause offence no matter how you word it. Walk it back before he gets that far and things will be better.

As to how, you are allowed to change your mind. Think about the pros and cons. Even better talk it out with someone (husband / wife / parent etc). Then you can honestly go back in and honestly say "I know I said that thing about 25 percent, but I was talking to my wife and she mentioned some personal reasons the new place would be better. I wanted to let you know as soon as possible so that you don't waste your time pushing for this with the higher ups. Sorry about all that, and please let me know what I need to do to train my replacement."

Comment: Don't lie. If there are real personal reason, than that's ok, but don't invent them or make up that "you wife" has them.

Comment: I agree, don't lie. That is why I said actually have the conversation. In such a conversation the full impact will become clear. But there will be personal reasons, because we are human people. Whether it is long hours or a fractious boss or just demoralising work, that will have an impact on you and your nearest and dearest. The tact here is in citing the effects rather than the cause, since the cause could imply both a greater level of accusation and an undesirable implication of "you just have to change this thing."

Answer (score 5):

Polite doesn’t have to be devious or untruthful.  It may still hurt their feelings, but that’s not necessarily wrong or bad and you at least provide a small opportunity for them to learn how they might improve themselves.  Also, by succumbing to the pressure you’ve already backed yourself a bit into a corner.  They’ll already be offended that they gave you what they perceived you wanted only to have you turn them down again.

Be honest, but constructive.  Instead of, “I hate this place!” phrase more like, “the new environment is better suited to me.”  Where possible, speak more in terms of whatever challenges you have with the company not suiting you or better yet you not being suited to it.  “The company doesn’t suit me,” sounds like you’re telling the company doesn’t meet some standard and it’s their fault.  “I don’t think I’m quite cut out for how we do things,” softens it more to accepting that it’s you that would need to change, but that’s not going to happen.

Consider something like the following:

> “[Manager], I do appreciate the efforts to keep me here.  After some
>   consideration, it’s a move I need to make and the compensation is not
>   the main factor.  There are some aspects of how things operate here
>   that I am just not well suited to and I think the new job is a better
>   fit for me.”

This may not be as emotional as a personal or romantic relationship, but you’re still ending a relationship.  The emotions are different levels but the basic principles still apply.  By making them think there’s a chance to retain you, you’ve already started stringing them along.  There’s a cliché about breaking up a relationship, “It’s not you.  It’s me.”  It not only takes the blame from the other party, but also implies that they have no control to change things.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is about how to say "no" politely. Just mentioning that "no" MUST be your answer; don't even think about taking their offer.

A polite way would be "Sorry, but I made up my mind and will change to new company. I agreed to this and I wouldn't break my promise". A less polite way would be "You agreed to a 25% raise now. That means you paid me 25% less than I was worth for the last year. I made my decision not based on what you offer now, but on what you paid me over the last year. "

If they continue to try to convince you to stay, you repeat the polite answer or the less polite answer. If they still continue, you repeat the same answer and so on. Nobody forces you to come up with more or different answers. They may try; that's a negotiating tactic. You counteract that tactics by just ignoring it. You have one answer, and you stick to that. Some people feel uncomfortable repeating the same answer again and again, and then they use a different answer and put themselves into a worse position. So don't feel uncomfortable. Stay with your initial answer.

Don't think for a second that you can only leave if you can tell the previous company why you are leaving. That's not a requirement. The only requirement is that *you* want to leave.

PS. There have been quite a few posts recently about leaving and counter offers. Personally, at the time I start looking for a new position, I have mentally divorced the old company. So there is no going back. For tactical reasons and as a professional, I will continue doing my job, and not tell that I will be leaving until things are ready, but I will leave.

Answer (score 1):

You have handed in your notice, so don’t rescind it.

If they actually match it then that will be a surprise as they tend to “lowball” as they think you don’t want the hassle of changing.

Since you have decided then stick with it - they may increase the money but the other issues won’t change.

So if you have handed in the notice, then say “Sorry, I’m not changing my mind, I’m still resigning”.

Comment: Thanks. But how to politely decline if suppose they match the offer and ask me to stay there itself? When you say " they may increase the money but the other issues won’t change.", what do you mean ?

Comment: “I don’t like the work environment” : those issues...

Comment: Yes. I handed in the notice. They pressured me because of which I told if they match the hike, I would stay. But if I say that I am still resigning even after the match the hike, what to say ? It would not be right, right?

Comment: @Newbie why don’t you expand on the other issues?

Comment: I am just not comfortable to say that I don't like this work environment. If I say now, after the give the hike, they would ask like, why didn't you tell this in the first place? Thats why I am asking for a polite way of turning this down